# How to convert openfire offlineDate into the correct datetime in php

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

How can i get and convert the xmpp(openfire) Last Logout time in a '**Y-m-d H:i:s**' format using php ?

```
offlineDate=001457169225070
```

I want to convert this offlineDate into '**Y-m-d H:i:s**' format in php.

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This timestamp '`1457169225070`' computed by openfire represents the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. 
So, i convert it to the number of seconds and used `date()` function

```
<?php
    $timestamp = (int) (1457169225070/1000);
    print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016-03-05 09:13:45
```